# How to get QR Code for ETH Wallet address using Ether.js, Web3 or other JavaScript libraries?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, metamask, etherscan

I was wondering if there is a way to grab a Blockchain address QR Code for the 0x000...
Can I grab a Metamasks Users QR Code for their Wallet Address?

-I'd like the QR to be the same as on Etherscan or from your Wallet so generating a new QR is not the option I'd like to take. *Unless there was a way to make the QR go to a specific route like OpenSea